# Need the easiest way to align JButtons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

im creating a gui and i want to align some JButtons. Could anyone share 
some code for the easiest way to do this. 
I need to hard code it, not drag and drop the buttons. 
Many Thanks.
Dave.

Comment: What does "align" mean? Horizontal, vertical, diagonal, circular? Each layout manager is designed to layout components differently.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with any layout manager. And no, I'm not giving you code. Instead, read [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and come to your own conclusion.